# Windows 7 can't install anything including windows updates

Tags: windows-7

Installed windows 7, vs2010 and sql 2008 w/ SP1 without a hitch.   Went to install live mesh and it complained that another instance of the installation was running (which to my knowledge was not).   I managed to get live mesh installed, then I got the same kind of error from Adobe Reader.   "Error 1500. Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one.",  Shutdown/Reboot does not cure the problem.   Running Windows Update now, I get "Code 80070652  Windows Update encountered an unknown error."

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thinkhard's answer is correct, the easiest way to avoid this is probably to install SQL Server before VS10. If you miss this, I found that by disabling the ".NET Runtime Optimization Service v4..[etc].._X86" and then running the VS 2010 web installer's "repair" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Developers who use the Windows Installer can set several "must reboot" [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372059(VS.85).aspx). Subsequent program installers which also use the Windows Installer Service will see that the system has been set to wait for a restart, and will not commence installs until this restart has been accomplished.

See also the [MsiSystemRebootPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370492(VS.85).aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have rebooted to no avail.  I can't seem to install anything really, now that this problem has cropped up.

Comment: Hmm. It's possible one of the installs you already did, has not completed or had an error and thus hasn't cleared the reboot pending property. If you don't find anything relevant in the Application Log, then you should probably uninstall/reinstall one or both of the progs you've already installed. Good luck!

Comment: I'm unable to add/remove programs because of the same issue (another installation is running)...

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress key exists.   I tried deleting this key and rebooting but it returns each time.   I looked in the .ipi file and found references to VS 9.0\Common 7\IDE which was installed with SQL 2008

I have a feeling that this has to do with the installation of SQL 2008, which I installed two instances of back-to-back.  I am going to re-install windows7 and only one instance of SQL 2008 and immediately apply SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Installers can also fail if there is anything under RunOnce key in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

After re-installing windows 7 I installed SQL Server 2008 before VS 2010 and immediately applied the service pack.   prior to this I had installed VS 2010 then SQL Server 2008 and another named instance of SQL 2008 somehow during that second installation the MSI believed there to be another installation in progress.   If you take the path I have do what the SQL 2008 installer says and install SP1 before doing anything else.

Comment: ALWAYS install SQL Server before anything else.  I have never had success installing Office 2007 or Visual Studio 2005/2008 before SQL Server 2005/2008.  Glad you got everything working!

Answer (score 1):

check event log... it should have error like "....\public assemblies\en" Folder is missing. Make sure the folder exists and it should fix the issue.